# How does ls sort filenames?

Tags: c, linux, bash, sorting, unix

I'm trying to write a function that mimics the output of the ls command in Unix. I was originally trying to perform this using scandir and alphasort, and this did indeed print the files in the directory, and it did sort them, but for some reason, this sorted list does not seem to match the same "sorted list" of filenames that ls gives.

For example, if I have a directory that contains file.c, FILE.c, and ls.c.

ls displays them in the order: file.c FILE.c ls.c
But when I sort it using alphasort/scandir, it sorts them as: FILE.c file.c ls.c

How does ls sort the files in the directory such that it gives such a differently ordered result?

Comment: `ls` uses its own custom string comparison while `alphasort` is just an implementation of `strcmp`

Comment: @MDXF I figured as much about alphasort :/ do you know the specifics of ls's custom string comparison, or where I could read more about it? I need to mimic ls's output so I'd like to learn what it does differently from alphasort/strcmp.

Comment: ls has a basic default sort which puts things in strcmp order, but it can be influenced by locale. To understand locales you could start with http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html and for string comparison specifcally, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcoll.html

Comment: The [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=tree;f=src;h=f0ac9e8d25f0f89731fbb3cb61604e7cfeacf7f1;hb=HEAD) is your best reference.

Comment: @kaylum The source code's so massive and complex it's near impossible to tell what's what

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thank you so much! I'll start by reading those.

Comment: There are probably easier places to start than the full specifications... I just don't know where they are. My interaction with locales consists of knowing how to get rid of them so I can have sane sorting, with Makefile and README at the top of the list (that's why they're spelled that way, so they don't get lost in the middle!)

Comment: If this is a programming-related question, you're Doing It Wrong (and if you're asking for reasons that *aren't* related to programming, consider [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow). **[`ls` should not be used programmatically](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**. Metadata lookups should use tools with facilities built for the purpose -- in the GNU world, `find -printf`, `stat --format`, etc; this is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To emulate default `ls -1` behaviour, make your program locale-aware by calling

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

near the beginning of your `main()`, and use

```
count = scandir(dir, &array, my_filter, alphasort);
```

where `my_filter()` is a function that returns 0 for names that begin with a dot `.`, and 1 for all others. `alphasort()` is a POSIX function that uses the locale collation order, same order as `strcoll()`.

The basic implementation is something along the lines of

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define  _ATFILE_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void my_print(const char *name, const struct stat *info)
{
    /* TODO: Better output; use info too, for 'ls -l' -style output? */
    printf("%s\n", name);
}

static int my_filter(const struct dirent *ent)
{
    /* Skip entries that begin with '.' */
    if (ent->d_name[0] == '.')
        return 0;

    /* Include all others */
    return 1;
}

static int my_ls(const char *dir)
{
    struct dirent **list = NULL;
    struct stat     info;
    DIR            *dirhandle;
    int             size, i, fd;

    size = scandir(dir, &list, my_filter, alphasort);
    if (size == -1) {
        const int cause = errno;

        /* Is dir not a directory, but a single entry perhaps? */
        if (cause == ENOTDIR && lstat(dir, &info) == 0) {
            my_print(dir, &info);
            return 0;
        }

        /* Print out the original error and fail. */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", dir, strerror(cause));
        return -1;
    }

    /* We need the directory handle for fstatat(). */
    dirhandle = opendir(dir);
    if (!dirhandle) {
        /* Print a warning, but continue. */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", dir, strerror(errno));
        fd = AT_FDCWD;
    } else {
        fd = dirfd(dirhandle);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        struct dirent *ent = list[i];

        /* Try to get information on ent. If fails, clear the structure. */
        if (fstatat(fd, ent->d_name, &info, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) == -1) {
            /* Print a warning about it. */
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", ent->d_name, strerror(errno));
            memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
        }

        /* Describe 'ent'. */
        my_print(ent->d_name, &info);
    }

    /* Release the directory handle. */
    if (dirhandle)
        closedir(dirhandle);

    /* Discard list. */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(list[i]);
    free(list);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
            if (my_ls(argv[arg])) {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (my_ls(".")) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I deliberately made this more complex than strictly needed for your purposes, because I did not want you to just copy and paste the code. It will be easier for you to compile, run, and investigate this program, then port the needed changes -- possibly just the one `setlocale("", LC_ALL);` line! -- to your own program, than try and explain to your teacher/lecturer/TA why the code looks like it was copied verbatim from somewhere else.

The above code works even for files specified on the command line (the `cause == ENOTDIR` part). It also uses a single function, `my_print(const char *name, const struct stat *info)` to print each directory entry; and to do that, it does call `stat` for each entry.

Instead of constructing a path to the directory entry and calling `lstat()`, `my_ls()` opens a directory handle, and uses `fstatat(descriptor, name, struct stat *, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW)` to gather the information in basically the same manner as `lstat()` would, but `name` being a relative path starting at the directory specified by `descriptor` (`dirfd(handle)`, if `handle` is an open `DIR *`).

It is true that calling one of the stat functions for each directory entry is "slow" (especially if you do `/bin/ls -1` style output). However, the output of `ls` is intended for human consumption; and very often piped through `more` or `less` to let the human view it at leisure. This is why I would personally do not think the "extra" stat() call (even when not really needed) is a problem here. Most human users I know of tend to use `ls -l` or (my favourite) `ls -laF --color=auto` anyway. (`auto` meaning ANSI colors are used only if standard output is a terminal; i.e. when `isatty(fileno(stdout)) == 1`.)

In other words, now that you have the `ls -1` order, I would suggest you modify the output to be similar to `ls -l` (dash ell, not dash one). You only need to modify `my_print()` for that.

Comment: For the completeness and content, you get a gold star (eh, the best I can do is an upvote :)

Comment: You are incredible. Thank you so much for going above and beyond in your answer! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

In alphanumeric (dictionary) order.

That changes with language, of course. Try:

```
$ LANG=C ls -1
FILE.c
file.c
ls.c
```

And:

```
$ LANG=en_US.utf8 ls -1
file.c
FILE.c
ls.c
```

That is related to [the "collating order"](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8177/13w/notes/000_character_sets.html). Not a simple issue by any measure.

Comment: Yes it does use a (modified) [strcoll](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=cb381116394a023d50e143e0463f239a2128840e;hb=HEAD#l3444). However; From your link: "Collation order is the dictionary order".